# C# List IList or IEnumerable as argument

Tags: c#, list, methods, arguments, ienumerable

If I want to take a List as an argument of a method, Resharper gives a hint that using the IList interface might be a better idea. If I then replace List with IList, Resharper suggests IEnumerable. In Java I would also take the List interface and not ArrayList as an argument. But is it really good looking code to use iEnumerable as an argument? Is this good practice to use IEnumerable if no functionality of IList or List are required?

Comment: *"Is this good practice to use IEnumerable if no functionality of IList or List are required?"* -- Yes.

Comment: Yes because it opens up what you can pass like an array or a lazy loaded Linq query.

Comment: It's always good to provide methods that are reusable. If you ask for the base interface of all generic collections you can use this method with many types, not only with lists. `IList<T>` covers lists and arrays, but if you don't need methods of `IList<T>` you can use `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: if your question is answered, please mark it as such. thank you for the upvote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is [the article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/05/18/return-the-most-specific-type-accept-the-most-generic-type/) that made me change my mind about all that and made me start following the principle of

> take the most generic type, return the most specific type

So to answer your question

> Is this good practice to use IEnumerable if no functionality of IList or List are required?

**yes, it is**

note: do not over do it ! I've seen code that accepted an `IEnumerable`, then threw an exception if the parameter wasn't a `List`. This is stupid. What the sentence I quoted above means is "don't ask for more specificity than you need"